# Refresh and Client side Authentication in UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've written a login service that stores a cookie (with NgCookie) that works great in my application except when it comes time to refresh the page or open a new tab etc.  My layout in app.js is something like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['listofDependencies'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider.state('login',
          view: login.html,
          controller: loginCtrl,
          authenticate: false)
        .state('bunchOfOtherStates',
          view: states.html,
          controller: statesCtrl,
          authenticate: true)
        .run(function($rootScope, $state, $cookieStore) {
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $location) {
              if (toState.authenticate && !$cookieStore.get('whatever')) {
                $state.go('login');
              }
            });
```

When I implement this a get a number of problems.  The first is that when the application loads it doesn't redirect to the login url.
I'm a newb to ui-router and I haven't quite seen a layout like this when haunting the stackoverflow posts for this.  Any suggestions?

Edit: The real troubling behavior is that when I navigate to the login and then refresh once i'm logged in the application redirects to the login page again.

Comment: instate of cookieStore use session storage

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan you mean $window.sessionStorage?

Comment: @arturobelano you can use also `localstorage ` or you can make a call back to the server to check if the user is already authenticated, that will be more secure. however in your example it's normal that you will not be redirected to the login page when you load your app as `!$cookieStore.get('whatever')` will not be validated so the if condition will not be fulfilled.

Comment: @MohamedNAOUALI sure there's a logic error there, but I can't seem to force the application to redirect to the login on load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage for the purpose.

Steps:

```
add ngStorage.min.js in your file
add ngStorage dependency in your module
add $sessionStorage module in your controller
use $sessionStorage.key = value
```

Answer (score 0):

would you check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3kImqU?p=preview) with an example of what you are looking for.
    app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, Auth) {

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

  var shouldLogin = toState.data !== undefined
                && toState.data.requireLogin 
                && !Auth.isLoggedIn ;

  // NOT authenticated - wants any private stuff
  if(shouldLogin)
  {
    $state.go('login');
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }


  // authenticated (previously) comming not to root main
  if(Auth.isLoggedIn) 
  {
    var shouldGoToMain = fromState.name === ""
                      && toState.name !== "main" ;

    if (shouldGoToMain)
    {
        $state.go('main');
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
    return;
  }

  // UNauthenticated (previously) comming not to root public 
  var shouldGoToPublic = fromState.name === ""
                    && toState.name !== "public"
                    && toState.name !== "login" ;

  if(shouldGoToPublic)
  {
      $state.go('public');console.log('p')
      event.preventDefault();
  } 

  // unmanaged
});
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried something similar to this, but on refresh even if the user is logged in it goes to login.

Comment: @arturobelano is it possible to share a plunker so we can check together?